# How can I delay the rotations on a driver before I want the ball to move?

Tags: drivers, path

[image: Driver Expression]
Currently the ball in my file rotates for the entire duration of my animation. But I would like it to only start rotating at frame 375 and end at frame 700. Is there a code I have to add in the expression section of my driver? If yes can someone please explain to me how it works? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the rotation to be driven by scene time, that's just keyframing; no driver required.

But if you want the rotation to be driven by location on the curve-path, then you *could* construct an expression, perhaps involving `lerp()` and `clamp()`, relating the curve's `eval_time` to the X rotation of the ball.

However, it might be easier and more flexible to leave the `eval_time` as it is, and use the f-curve associated with the driver to *draw* the function relating the driving property on X to the driven property on Y:

[image]

With the right set-up (I have to set my driver-editor window to 'Stay On Top'), you can watch the animation while tweaking the f-curve. It's still fiddly, bit a lot less fiddly, IMO,  than going backwards and forwards, tweaking values in a long expression.

[image]

**Edit:** (response to commentary)

You've got 2 methods of animating an object along a curve fighting one another. In your version:

- The `Evaluation Time` of your curve is running continuously. The rotation of your ball is driven by that, so it's spinning continuously, too.
- The ball is prevented from moving along the curve according to `Evaluation Time` by being set to 'Fixed Position' and having its `Offset` key-framed manually.

The location of the ball is ignoring `Evaluation Time`, the spin of the ball is not.

Either drive both the spin and the location by `Offset`, or both the spin and location by `Evaluation Time`. Personally I would prefer to drive both by `Offset`, forgetting the (legacy?) `Evaluation Time` altogether, to make the possibility of animating more than one object down the curve at different speeds cleaner.

But your driver uses `Evaluation Time`, so we'll go with that. In the adjusted version below, I've unchecked 'Fixed Position' on the ball, wiped its `Offset` key-frames, and, instead, key-framed `Evaluation Time` on the curve, imitating your previous locations as closely as I can, so now the location and spin are in sync.

[image]

Comment: nice explanation, but i assume he wants the ball to "physically" accurately roll on the curve no matter how long the curve is ;) But of course, this assumption has no proof and unfortunately he didn't describe this detail in his question

Comment: Hi, @Chris! You could be right, there, although I didn't read it that way. ... I guess we'll just have to wait and see. Maybe I'll wind up adding to my stash of deleted answers :)

Comment: welcome to MY world!! :D

Comment: Hello everyone, @Robin-Betts, thank you for the explanation. The Problem with your simulation is the rotation of your ball, it is not constant. Chris is correct in his assumption, the ball must rotate accurately. The first 374 frames, the ball should remain stationary in it's position as a camera moves in to the appropriate place. At frame 375, the ball starts the path follow using the driver attached to the ball. At Frame 700, the ball arrives at the end of the path follow and stops rotating.

Comment: Hello @Robin-Betts, how can i insert a blend file here? I believe this would help resolve my dilemma as it would become very clear and apparent after viewing viewing. Thanks again for your time, patience and understaNDING

Comment: @robin-betts [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=QgRV0kLw" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/QgRV0kLw/)

Comment: @nicknikolaidis Sorry for the delay, had to be AFK. See edit; I hope it's a fix.

Comment: @RobinBetts sorry for the delay. Thank in effort to help. Unfortunately, it hasn't resolved my issue. I'm trying to research and read up as much as possible however, I'm still stumped. The answer to getting the motion required is in the driver / expression.(due to precise rotations needed)  -2*40/2.25*(eval_time/100) the sphere is following the path but constantly rotating from start to finish. I only the action of the sphere to begin rotating at frame 375 when path follow constraint begins and end at frame 700. If you can write an expression, that would be awesome, if not that's ok. Thanks

Comment: Hi, @nicknikolaidis Forgive me, I don't understand this discrepancy. The ball in the RB version linked in the answer is using  _your_ driver, with exactly your expression, unchanged. Its spin is strictly related to the travel along the path, so there is no slip. The spin is _not_ constant. The more slowly the ball moves along the path, the more slowly it spins. You're not by any chance rendering the old copy, which I left in the file, hidden in the viewport, but not to renders? Make sure the old version is switched off to renders, or deleted?

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you for all your help. Your assistance guided me towards the answer I needed. I'll make sure in the future to be more precise with the wording and provide a blend file for reference.  I also checked the answer as being helpful.

Comment: @nicknikolaidis Thanks.. if a misunderstanding remains, and you still need a fix, I'm sure we can cover it, given a clear explanation. These things can be tough to describe.